# Does infinite system of measurable subsets of a measurable set have a measurable intersection

Tags: measure-theory

Let $U$ be a finitely-measurable set, $G_1, G_2, \dots$ are its measurable subsets such that for every $i$ $\mu(G_i) \ge \alpha > 0$. Does there necessarily exist a measurable subset $\Gamma$ such that it is a subset of infinitely many $G_i$ and $\mu(\Gamma)>0$?

If we establish that there is a subset $G_{n_1}$ such that for infinitely many $j$ $\mu(G_{n_1}\cap G_j)\ge \frac{2\alpha}{3}$ then we can prove the theorem by induction. To find such $G_{n_1}$ I tried simply throwing out all subsets that have intersection greater than $\frac{2\alpha}{3}$ with $G_1$, then assume $G_2$ to be the subset with the least number still not thrown out and throw out all subsets that intersect $G_2$ by more than $\frac{2\alpha}{3}$ and so on. In the end we are left with an infinite system of subsets such that none of them have measure of their intersection $\ge \frac{2\alpha}{3}$. This is where I get stuck. Does anyone have any ideas how to finish the proof? Or maybe the statement I am trying to prove is incorrect?

Comment: Why not $\Gamma=\emptyset$?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to mention that I am looking for a subset of positive measure

Comment: There are easy counter-examples if the measure is not finite: $G_i=(i,i+1)$

Comment: Yeah, another one. $\mu(U)$ has to be $<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a $\Gamma$ may not exist. Consider, for example, the probability space $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $G_n$ be the collection of elements whose values at the $n$-th coordinate are 0. Then $\mu(G_n) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$ and the intersection of any infinitely many such $G_n$ will always have measure 0, so no such $\Gamma$ can exist.